# SQL Server - How to get the greatest number from a repetitive date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help Needed: SQL Server: how to get the greatest number from a repetitive date? See example of my actual and desired results below:

```
SELECT 
    Project.Project_Title,
    cumulativebyday.Date,
    ROUND(cumulativebyday.TaskCumulativeWork, 1) AS Task_Cum_Work
FROM 
    Project
INNER JOIN 
    cumulativebyday ON Project.ProjectID = cumulativebyday.ProjectID
ORDER BY
    ProjectTitle ASC, TimeByDay DESC, TaskCumulativeWork DESC;
```

Current results of this query:

```
    Project_Title | Date      | Task_Cum_Work
    --------------+-----------+--------------
    Project 1     | 2/14/2018 | 18
    Project 1     | 2/14/2018 | 15
    Project 1     | 2/14/2018 | 12
    Project 1     | 2/13/2018 | 17
    Project 1     | 2/13/2018 | 14
    Project 1     | 2/13/2018 | 11
```

Desired results for this query:

```
    Project_Title | Date      | Task_Cum_Work
    --------------+-----------+--------------
    Project 1     | 2/14/2018 | 18
    Project 1     | 2/13/2018 | 17
```

Thank you!

Comment: add the code that you have use but it sound like you need to try [Group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql)

Comment: very poor description. It is nearly impossible to understand data type. No SQL Given. No Datastructure.

Comment: I have added the code. Thanks for your feedback and any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do this by Aggregating the results. We specify `Max()` function around the field and then add the other fields to the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT 
    Project.Project_Title
    , cumulativebyday.Date
    , Max(Round(cumulativebyday.TaskCumulativeWork,1)) as Task_Cum_Work

FROM 
    Project

INNER JOIN 
    cumulativebyday
  ON 
    Project.ProjectID=cumulativebyday.ProjectID
GROUP BY  Project.Project_Title
    , cumulativebyday.Date
Order by 
    ProjectTitle ASC
    , TimeByDay DESC
    , TaskCumulativeWork Desc;
```